# PHP Logical Operator matching in strings

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I'm putting together a search form. I want to provide the user the option of searching with logical operators. Examples of search queries:

- `red || ((green && pink))`
- `!red && !green`

The data which is being searched is stored in an array. I have a few ways I can provide this functionality by chopping the search string up but I'm wondering if anyone knows of any modules which I could utilize before is start coding something from scratch?

I should also mention that I'm aware of security issues surrounding techniques but I'm not worried about SQL injections etc. as this tool isn't going to be on a public facing server.

Comment: could you let the user search with regular expressions?

Comment: Just a caveat, code written for private servers has a tendency to later be copied and used for public servers without much scrutiny. People tend to cut and paste. You might preface it with a huge warning or, better yet, include code to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: Are you using MySQL? Its fulltext search feature supports boolean searching automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into using a proper Lexer or PEG, such as [php-peg](https://github.com/hafriedlander/php-peg) or [PHP_LexerGenerator](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_LexerGenerator), which allows you to generate code that parses and validates a grammar for such uses.

You might also want to look at tools like [ANTLRWorks](http://www.antlr3.org/works/index.html), helping debugging and creating grammars.

Comment: Wow! I've been toying with PHP for years now and I've never even heard of these before! Thank you very much @fiskfisk. I'm having a play with PEG now. I shall share my results once I've completed the task.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague but I think that eval() could be used to easily solve your problem, if you don't know it executes code that you give it as a string.

Comment: No, never use eval for something "the user provides ..". In fact, never use eval. Never. (if you don't know when you can break this rule, don't break it)

Comment: He just said he didn't care about security, I know eval is a terrible function to use but for his purposes it seemed like a good choice. If used with a function like filter it could actually be a very simple solution to his problem.